# Event Handler is not responding in jquery

Tags: jquery, event-handling

jquery:

```
var pop = $('.popupdiv');
disable();
function disable()
{
   pop.slideDown(1000);
}
$( "body").keyup(function()
{
    $("body") .mousedown(function()
   {
      alert("hii");
  })
  pop.slideUp(1000);
})
```

In the above example as soon as document is loaded "disable" method excute as expected,but after the "keyup" event "slideUp" function excute but "mousedown" event is not responding.After deletion of "slideUp" method "mousedown" event responds. I want know why it is happening? What is the solution of it? I want both "slideUp" method and "mousedown" event responds after the "keyup" event.

Comment: Why you are binding `mousedown` in `keyup` handler?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that once you've attached the mousedown event-handler to that element, it's there; no need to do it again. Hence, this is enough:

```
$('body').keyup(function() {}).mousedown(function() {});
```

If you are trying to achieve keyup+mousedown combo on element, then you need to re-think this.
Perhaps something like:

```
a = false;

$('body').keyup(function() {
    a = true;
}).mousedown(function() {
    if (a) {
        a = false;

        alert("hii");

        pop.slideUp(1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong, you nest a mousedown event handler inside a keyup event handler and both assigned on the same element.(Mousedown while keyup on same element doesnt seem logical)

Instead the correct is :

```
var pop = $('.popupdiv');
disable();
function disable()
{
   pop.slideDown(1000);
}
$( "body").keyup(function() {
//DO something on keyup
}).mousedown(function() {
//Do something on mousedown
});
```